# IloEnv env ; don't work in the dbug and it can access to it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cplex, opl, rational-team-concert

i run a code in c++ in debug version step by step (F11) using visual studio2010 linked with cplex 12.4, so i obtained this error and message at the line where i declare IloEnv env ; it don't work , and i don't know why , ididn't find all these reperatory in my own pc so can someone help me to how fix it
those the errors :

Call stack location:

VRWRMS.exe!IloEnv::IloEnv() line 723

Source file information:
Finding source for 'd:\softwarefactory\hudson_slave\builds_x86vs2010\workspace\rb.concert-wks.x86_windows_vs2010\src\iloenv.cpp'. Checksum: MD5 {80 35 f8 e7 7f 34 ea e6 49 c9 f4 7f b1 a a2 ba}

File 'd:\softwarefactory\hudson_slave\builds_x86vs2010\workspace\rb.concert-wks.x86_windows_vs2010\src\iloenv.cpp' does not exist.
Searching for 'd:\softwarefactory\hudson_slave\builds_x86vs2010\workspace\rb.concert-wks.x86_windows_vs2010\src\iloenv.cpp' in the script documents...

Searching for 'd:\softwarefactory\hudson_slave\builds_x86vs2010\workspace\rb.concert-wks.x86_windows_vs2010\src\iloenv.cpp' in projects.

The file was not found in a project.
Search in the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src'...

Search in the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc'...

Search in the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl'...

Search in the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include'...

Search in the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc'...

Search in the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfcm'...

Search in the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl'...

Search in the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src'...
Search in the directory ''...

Search in the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include'...

Search in the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include'...

Search in the directory 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include'...

Search in the directory 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include'...

Search in the directory ''...

The debug source file settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not prompt the user to find the file: d:\softwarefactory\hudson_slave\builds_x86vs2010\workspace\rb.concert-wks.x86_windows_vs2010\src\iloenv. cpp.

The debugger could not find the source file 'd:\softwarefactory\hudson_slave\builds_x86vs2010\workspace\rb.concert-wks.x86_windows_vs2010\src\iloenv.cpp'.

Comment: Please don't show screenshots of error messages, just post the text (especially if its not in english). Do you actually need to debug into this library? If you do then you'll either need to download the source code and tell VS where to find it or bulid the library from source yourself

Comment: @AlanBirtles i remove the sreenshots and translate the messages that i got in english o

Comment: CPLEX is IBM's commercial code, so you absolutely will NOT be able to get the source code or debug into that code in any usable way (unless you are part of the IBM R&D team!). There are many thousands of people successfully using these libs every day, so I'd be pretty sure the error is in your code or the way you build it.